# How should I partition a 64GB SSD for multiple Linux installations?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, partition, ssd

Are there any things I should keep in mind in order to increase the longevity and efficiency of my SSD?

Comment: This belongs on superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com.  It is very unlikely that anyone would be running multiple installs on a server.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you partition your volume like this.

```
MBR partition 1 - 2GB. will be used as /boot, will be shared by all installs
MBR partition 2 - all remaining space into an LVM volume group

LVM - Logical volume /home start with a 4-8GB and more if desired
LVM - LV root-debian root partition for an install of debian
LVM - LV root-centos root partition for an install of centos
LVM - LV-root-foobar root partition for an install of foobar
```

It is extremely easy to LVM to expand a volume, so make all your logical volumes the small, and leave yourself lots of free space on the volume group.  When you need more storage allocated it as needed.

See the [LVM howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/) for details on LVM.

You can use a shared /boot partition for multiple installations, but it will require some manual tweaking of your bootloader configuration, and you should keep backups of those files as you are doing your installs.

Unless you are really low on memory, you might want to skip setting up any swap.